# clang-format Overriding multi-line comments for WebKit style

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to use clang-format to clean up code in my repository. We are using the WebKit style as the basis for formatting, however we also want to make sure that multi line comments are formatted correctly.

From my understanding it is possible override the formatting rules of given style by define the .clang-format file as such:

```
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AlignTrailingComments: true
```

This way clang-format should align the trailing comments.

Given the input file:

```
    /**
     * This is a multi-line comment
     */
    void function() {
        /**
         * This is comment inside the function
         */
    }
```

My expectation is the following output

```
/**
 * This is a multi-line comment
 */
void function()
{
    /**
     * This is comment inside the function
     */
}
```

However what I get is:

```
/**
     * This is a multi-line comment
     */
void function()
{
    /**
         * This is comment inside the function
         */
}
```

I've tried dumping out the formatting options of Webkit into a .clang-format file and changing the AlignTrailingComments from false to true. This doesn't make and difference either.

Is there some option in the Webkit style that is interfering with the AlignTrailingComments option?

Comment: Came here to ask the same. I don't have any BasedOnStyle set, and I think AlignTrailingComments is not related (it's for comments starting with `//` after a line of code, no?). Looks like a bug: start of the block gets aligned, but the rest doesn't.

Comment: I have the same problem. And none of the 3 answers here seems to answer the question yet.

Answer (score 2):

`AlignTrailingComments` aligns comments trailing code in consecutive lines:

```
int short;        // short
int longlonglong; // long
```

Answer (score 2):

The real issue here is the pre-defined `WebKit` style setting `ColumnLimit: 0`. This somehow disables the indentation of non-first-line-part of multi-line comments. (And this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere - I think it's a bug.)

One workaround would be to set the column limit to something reasonable, like `ColumnLimit: 80` or possibly `ColumnLimit: 120`. Possibly you could do this once, and then switch back to your usual `ColumnLimit: 0` - but setting the column limit once will likely change formatting on many code lines, which will not be restored when you change the column limit back to zero, so probably not what you want.

`AlignTrailingComments` does not relate to this at all. As another answer explains, this is for aligning the trailing comments at the end of code lines. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) for more details.

I don't believe `CommentPragmas` will help either. I'm pretty sure this only prevents `clang-format` from adding line breaks to those comments, but does not prevent indentation changes. (And this is not really documented either.) Anyway, what is needed here is *adjusting* the indentation, not leaving it alone, so `CommentPragmas` almost seems like the opposite of what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround: use `CommentPragmas` with a regex to mark those comments as untouchable.

Comment: Actually, the OP has the opposite problem. His comments are not getting un-indented as he would like. In any case, `CommentPragmas` doesn't disable indentation, just other stuff like line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by making the following adjustments:

1. I modified the `ColumnLimit` setting in the `.clang-format` file. Initially, it was set to `0`, but I changed it to `120`.
2. I enabled the `ReflowComments` setting, which was previously set to `false`. I updated this to `true`.
3. I reverted the file containing the problematic comment to its state prior to the incorrect formatting, and then reformatted the file.

To illustrate, my original comment block looked like this:

```c
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function       : Constructor
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description    : Constructor
Return values  : -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

After running `clang-format`, it was incorrectly formatted as follows:

```c
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function       : Constructor
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description    : Constructor
Return values  : -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

I then reverted all the files to their original state and re-ran `clang-format`. This resulted in the correctly formatted comment block:

```c
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Function       : Constructor
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Description    : Constructor
    Return values  : -
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

I hope this helps others who might be facing a similar issue.