# Wrong indentation of multiline comments in VSCode with C/C++ extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

It seems that the clang formatter of the C/C++ extension has difficulties when indenting multiline comments.

I get the following format when using the formatter (so just the first line is formatted properly):

```
     /**
* @brief Does cool stuff
*
* @param param1
* @returns myresult
*/
     bool myFunction(bool param1);
```

However I would expect the format to be:

```
     /**
     * @brief Does cool stuff
     *
     * @param param1
     * @returns myresult
     */
     bool myFunction(bool param1);
```

My VSCode Clang Format style:

```
{BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 3, ColumnLimit: 0, NamespaceIndentation: All, AlignTrailingComments: true}
```

Am I missing a Styleparameter or is this a bug in the formatter?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer your question, but your indentation of 3 is rather unorthodox. If your code is shared with other people, I would suggest to use an indentation width of 4.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Unfortunately this is a (imho strange) coding guideline of my company - so I'm restricted to this.

Comment: works for me as expected: [here](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) and in my VS 2019. So this must be some clang format setting or VSCode bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang-format Overriding multi-line comments for WebKit style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712729/clang-format-overriding-multi-line-comments-for-webkit-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `ColumnLimit: 0`. This somehow disables the indentation of the non-first-line-part of multi-line comments. (And this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere - I think it is a bug.) Probably the best workaround is to set `ColumnLimit` to some reasonable non-zero value.