# Enforcing formatting style block-comments

Tags: clang-format

I want to use clang-format to enforce either of the following formatting styles of block-comments:

1. Formatting style (1):

   ```cpp
   /*
    *  ...
    */
   ```
2. Formatting style (2):

   ```cpp
   /**
   ...
   */
   ```

How do I do this?

---

A more specific example: given this code

```cpp
/**
Starting from formatting style (1).
*/
void foo();

/**
 *  Starting from formatting style (2).
 */
void bar();
```

I want to use clang-format to switch between outputs:

1. Formatting style (1):

   ```cpp
   /**
    *  Starting from formatting style (1).
    */
   void foo();

   /**
    *  Starting from formatting style (2).
    */
   void bar();
   ```
2. Formatting style (2):

   ```cpp
   /**
   Starting from formatting style (1).
   */
   void foo();

   /**
   Starting from formatting style (2).
   */
   void bar();
   ```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712729/clang-format-overriding-multi-line-comments-for-webkit-style

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks, I already tried that before. Maybe I'm understanding something wrong, but that does not change anything to the formatting of the code I poster here. Specifically, I tried the option `AlignTrailingComments: true` as described in the OP

Comment: [The real issue here is the pre-defined `WebKit` style setting `ColumnLimit: 0.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439517/34989)

Comment: @Gerhard I guess my problem description might not have been sufficiently clear, I have edited. The problem is that I want `/**\n...\n*/` to be changed in `/**\n *  ...\n */`. This is currently not attempted at all. That is even more basic than the formatting going wrong